# Changing div colour with label and checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, input, label

I am trying to change the colour of the item1 div by checking the labels and it's inputs. For some reason, it only works when you check the first two checkboxes but not the last one.
Can you please explain why is this happenning?

```
  <style type="text/css">
     .item1 {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     }
     #item-1:checked + label .item1 {
     background: red;
     } 
     #item-2:checked + label .item1 {
     background: blue;
     }
     #item-3:checked + label .item1 {
     background: purple;
     }
  </style>


  <label for="item-1"> label 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="item-1">
  <label for="item-2"> label 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="item-2">
  <label for="item-3"> label 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="item-3">
  <div class="item1">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since you don't have closing tags for labels, after the browser will parse your html it will look like this:

```
<label for="item-1"> label 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="item-1">
    <label for="item-2"> label 2
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="item-2">
        <label for="item-3"> label 3
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="item-3">
            <div class="item1">
            </div>
        </label>
    </label>
</label>
```

And since there is no label after `<input type="checkbox" name="" id="item-3">` you can make it work by changing the last css rule:

```
#item-3:checked + .item1 {
  background: purple;
}
```